# Is there a keyboard shortcut for creating a shortcut file?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

What I seek is a shortcut key combination instead of right clicking a file and choosing 'Create shortcut' in Windows 10.

Comment: If you don't mind a few keypresses: Use the menu key (or if your keyboard does not have it CTRL-SHIFT-F10, followed by w, w, right arrow, s to create a shortcut. This could be turned into an auto-it or vbscript to execute these keystrokes based on a global hotkey. If your keyboard has a macro recorder, it can also be used of course. The w, w, right arrow, s may be different if your OS language is not english. Look for the underlined letters. If there are more, you may have to press it more than once.

Comment: My bad about the above. the above is for creating a new shortcut. Creating a shortcut to an existing file is CTRL-SHIFT-F10, s

Comment: @LPChip in between alt gr and r-ctrl I have a details key that does the equivalent of CTRL-SHIFT-F10. It's kinda hard to press with s but F10 is also hard to press with CTRL-SHIFT. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there a shortcut key combination to 'Create shortcut'?

Yes.

1. Select the file you wish to use to make the shortcut.
2. Press the "Menu" or "Application" key <kbd>[image]</kbd>, then <kbd>s</kbd>.

   If you don't have a <kbd>[image]</kbd> key, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd> instead.

   [image]

Notes:

- In my case I have to press <kbd>s</kbd> twice, then <kbd>enter</kbd>. because of another entry in the menu with the same shortcut.
- <kbd>s</kbd> may need to be replaced by another letter on non-English versions of Windows.
- You could program the required keystrokes into a macro program, such as [Auto-It](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), or even the keyboard itself (if you have a programmable keyboard) in order to make a "shorter" shortcut key combination.

Comment: In my case, enter isn't required. After clicking to "Menu" key and then 's', it creates the shortcut. Thank you for taking your time to present it.

Comment: @kittenparry Ah, that is because I have 2 s entries. Answer updated.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to make an appropriate answer with images similar to what I already mentioned in the comments. :) You could add that this can be automated using a macro program such as auto-it, or if the keyboard itself has this, it can be used as well.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks, I didn't even see your comments until after I had finished the answer. It took me some time to find a picture of the Menu key and then to write the rest of the answer - with the fiddly key formating :) I will add a note about AutoHotKey.